# How do i get the total amount of day in a month and omit weekend

Tags: c++

This is my program output:

```
Select A Month-Year: 

1. 8-2012
2. 9-2012
3. 10-2012
4. 11-2012
5. 12-2012
6. 1-2013
```

After user selects e.g 9-2012 which is next month, I want to be able to know how many days there are in the year 2012, month of September (9-2012).

Then how do I get all the dates that fall in the weekend (Saturday and Sunday) so I can omit those date too?

I am using `ctime` library for my date fetching for now.

Below is what I Done so far, but for Feburary, every leap year(4 years) it is 29 days.

How do i do a logic to handle that. I know the latest year is this year 2012 (this year), the next one will be 2016, but I want my program able handle at least 40 years from now.

```
if(month==4||month==6||month==9||month==11)
{
totalDays = 30;
}

if(month==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month== 10 || month==12 )
{
totalDays = 30;
}

if(month==2)
{
//February
totalDays = 28;

}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://pocoproject.org/slides/070-DateAndTime.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

`mktime` can do almost all of the work for you. To find the number of days between two dates, each specified by a `struct tm`, you could use:

```
int days_between (struct tm *tsa, struct tm *tsb) {
    time_t a = mktime(tsa);
    time_t b = mktime(tsb);
    return (b - a)/(60*60*24);
}
```

This divides the difference in seconds by the number of seconds in a day.

So the days of the year could be calculated like this:

```
int days_of_year (int y) {
    struct tm tsa = {0};
    struct tm tsb = {0};

    tsa.tm_mday = 1;
    tsa.tm_year = y - 1900;

    tsb.tm_mday = 1;
    tsb.tm_year = y + 1 - 1900;

    return days_between(&tsa, &tsb);
}
```

The days of the month is similar, but you would keep the year constant, and use the next month in `tsb`.

To calculate the number of weekdays, there are always at least 8 in the first 28 days. Then, depending on how many days there are in the month, you have to consider the remaining days. The `tm_wday` field provides the days since Sunday for the date in the `struct tm`.

```
    int dss = tsa.tm_wday;
    weekdays = 8;
    switch (days) {
    case 31: if (dss == 0 || dss == 6) weekdays += 1;
             dss = (dss + 1) % 7;
    case 30: if (dss == 0 || dss == 6) weekdays += 1;
             dss = (dss + 1) % 7;
    case 29: if (dss == 0 || dss == 6) weekdays += 1;
    default: break;
    }
```

The complete example can be found at http://ideone.com/qQo3U

To calculate leap year, the logic for the Gregorian Calendar is: A year is a leap year if the year is divisible by 4, except if it is also divisible by 100, in which case it is a leap year if it is divisible by 400.

```
int is_leap_year (int y) {
    return (y % 4) ? 0 : ((y % 100) ? 1 : !(y % 400));
}
```

However, `mktime` already knows about this, and can figure it out for you, as has already been demonstrated.

Comment: I know that's a pretty old answer but you should use [`difftime(b, a)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/) instead of `b - a` in `days_between`.

Comment: I am assuming POSIX and no overflow, so `b - a` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google found this link for calculating the day of the week: 
http://www.terra.es/personal2/grimmer/

You will have to do a bunch of handling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out which weekday the first day of the month is (use mktime). Work out the number of days in the month (and and be CAREFUL with February), and a little bit of arithmetic will then tell you how many Saturdays and Sundays there are.